# Matlab, Getting rid of for loop using one liner

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Lets assume we have some code. In Matlab editor:

```
x = zeros(1,10);
x(1,1) = 2;
for k = 1: 9
    x(k+1) = 10 * x(k);
end
```

Is it possible to write the equation without the for loop?

Comment: At least try to specify the language you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = 2 * 10.^(0:9);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. How to write the same equation when multiplier is not 10. Instead of 10 it will be a 2 by 2 matrix. The same generates error in Matlab when its a matrix and shows prompt that: matrix dimension must agree.!

Comment: As of Matlab 2016b, Matlab does automatic implicit matrix expansion so this works for me. See this post: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the logspace function:
    x=2*logspace(0,9,10)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because it is contrary to the rules of matrix multiplication.
My solution below, I used the free analogue of Matlab - Octave, which has a similar syntax:

```
X=randint(2) % Matrix of size 2 by 2
X =

   1   0
   0   0

Y=2 * 10.^X(:)
Y =

   20
    2
    2
    2
```

---

You have a right to multiply the matrix only this type:

M x **N** on **N** x P

The result is a matrix of the following dimensions:

M x P

---

See also:

[Element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html)

[Element-wise power](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html)

---

I hope this helped